# C ++ How to change the value of 4 bits in a 32 bit number

Tags: c++, mask

I have a 32-bit register that I need to manipulate. But I only need to change bits 12-15, and leave the rest of the bits unchanged.

[image: Register image]

I want to overwrite whatever is in bits 12-15 with 0x2 or 0b0010.

How can I do this in C++?

Here is an example code I have been trying.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint32_t x = 0x4D00D0F0;

    x |= 0x2 << 12; // shifting 0x2 12 bits to the left

    return 0;
}
```

My solution only seems to shift a 1 to bit 13, why is that?

Can I shift an entire 4-bit hex number?

Bottom line, I want x = 0x4D0020F0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, mask the original bits out to make sure they are zeroed and won't interfere with the value, you are going to "or" there:

`x & 0xffff0fff`

Then "or" the new bits into place:

`(x & 0xffff0fff) | (0x2 << 12)`

Answer (score 4):

In general `x = (x & ~mask) | (y & mask)` copies the bits in `mask` position from `y` to `x`.

In OP's case `mask = 0xF000` and `y = 0x2000`.